# EF 4.1 Generic Many-To-Many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, generics, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Need to build a tagging system of sorts in EF 4.1, which allows to query for all entities per tag, or all tags per entity.  Here's an abbreviated snapshot of my model:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    [Required]
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}

public class Tag : BaseEntity {
    // tag subscribers
    public List<King> Kings { get; set; }
    public List<Knight> Knights { get; set; }
    public List<Peasant> Peasants { get; set; }
}

public class King : BaseEntity {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Knight : BaseEntity {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Peasant : BaseEntity {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

(Yeah I know King, Knight and Peasant are the same here.  But as the messenger says in Monty Python and the Holy Grail: "It's only a model.")

So anyway, this model works nicely, but I would prefer a T generic list, rather than a specific cast.  Less tables in the db, less overhead when querying from tags to entities.  How could I convert all of the List<Entity> properties in Tag to a single generic List<T> where T : BaseEntity, and would this result in a single lookup table that I could query against for specific derivatives?  Something like:

```
 List<Knight> knightsByTag = Tags.Where(t => t.GetType() == typeof (Knight)).ToList();
```

EDIT: 
Yeesh.  Sorry, had some of the actual code still in there.

@DarthVader:

- Would like Tag to use one List property instead of the three List properties currently.
- Would like to be able to query all Tags associated with a Knight, or all Peasants associated with a tag, etc.
- Want to make sure that EF CodeFirst will be able to accurately resolve a generic list, preferably using a lookup table.

Comment: can you clarify and simplify your question? what are you trying to query? `Tags` doesnt have `Knight` as you define. how can u write the last query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have single list in `BaseEntity` you also have to drop your lists in child entities. You will end with something like:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    ...

    // tags
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag : BaseEntity {
    ...

    // tag subscribers
    public List<BaseEntity> Entities { get; set; }
}
```

If you have any specific constraints you will have to check them in the application prior to making relation between entity and tag. Any other way would  lead you to separate navigation property per entity and separate junction table per such relation.

All Tags associated with a Knight - this should work:

```
var tags = from k in context.Knights // or context.BaseEntities.OfType<Knight>()
           from t in k.Tags
           select t;
```

All Peasants associated with a tag - this should  work:

```
var peasants = from t in context.Tags
               from p in t.Entities.OfType<Peasant>()
               select p;
```

Beware that mapped inheritance has negative impact on query performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm concerned that `<BaseEntity>` contains a collection of a derivative...    Is a generic collection in `Tag` (e.g. `List<T> where T : BaseEntity`) not feasible?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  Ladislav, your answer wasn't quite what I was looking for, but that's because what I was looking for isn't really feasible.  So your answer is technically correct.  Thanks for the assist.